# JavaFX Multiple animated rectangles

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I'm trying to create a function that creates an animation in JavaFX of a rectangle moving in a straight line. I have a couple of rectangles so I will be calling this function a couple of times. What I want my program to do, is to create let's say 3 rectangles and move them up to a certain ending point with constant space between them. But when one rectangle gets into this ending point, I want it to vanish and then reappear at the bottom. The only solution, which I've came up with is to just create them all at the same starting point, call this function, wait some time and then call this function again creating another rectangle. It works well, but since it's inside the initializing function, my program waits a couple of seconds when I run it. Do you know any better way?

```
 public void initialize() throws InterruptedException { 

        animatePlainWave(rect1);
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        animatePlainWave(rect2);
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        animatePlainWave(rect3);
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        animatePlainWave(rect4);
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        animatePlainWave(rect5);
}
```

```
public void animatePlainWave(Node rectangle)
{
    TranslateTransition rectangleTransition = new TranslateTransition();
    rectangleTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(rectangle.getLayoutY()/100)); 
    rectangleTransition.setToY(650-rectangle.getLayoutY()); 
    rectangleTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
    rectangleTransition.setCycleCount(TranslateTransition.INDEFINITE); 
    rectangleTransition.setNode(rectangle);
    rectangleTransition.rateProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(1d, mySlider.valueProperty()));
    rectangleTransition.play();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want to stagger the start of each animation, in which case you can use the [`delay`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#delayProperty) property.

Comment: @Slaw But where should I use it? If I delete those Thread.sleep(1500) and instead I use rectangleTransition.setDelay(Duration.seconds(1.5));  inside my function, then all of my rectangles will overlap.

Comment: Use different delays for every `TranslateTransition`. Should be 1.5, 3 and 4.5 s.

Comment: You can add a `Duration` parameter to your `animatePlainWave` method that you use to set the `delay`. Then pass the appropriate `Duration` each time (see fabian's comment).